# How to reserve space inside scrollable column in PySimplegUI?

Tags: python, user-interface, layout, pysimplegui

So I want to have a column which is scrollable. There will be plenty of elements inside it. Among other things two canvases that will have matplotlib figures printed.

```
layout = [[sg.Column(layout, vertical_scroll_only=True, scrollable=True,size=(800,400))]]
```

I understand now that this reserves space for the column of width 800 and height 400. Inside it you can scroll the allocated space of the elements.

```
[sg.Button("Load CSVs", key="-loadcsv-")],
[sg.Canvas(key='-CANVAS2-' ),sg.InputText(size=(10,1),key="threshold"), sg.Button("Set Threshold", key="-threshold-")],
[sg.InputText(size=(50, 1), key='-MODELNAME-'), sg.FileBrowse("Load Model")]
```

This is part of what is inside the column. I understand I can reserve space for the canvas, so that it has some space before the figure is even drawn, but I don't want that look. And also the things after the canvas will still be pushed off the visible space.

How can I allocate the space inside the column?

**EDIT:**
I am adding two pictures, the first is the inital layout:

[image]

This is what happens when the matplotlib figure is inserted. Some of it just gets wiped out. I know I can pre-allocated the canvas size, but than I don't like the initial layout.
[image]

Comment: What this issue talked about ??? For my poor English, nothing understood.

Comment: I will add a picture later.

Comment: @JasonYang I added two picture, hope you can understand it better now.

Comment: "I know I can pre-allocated the canvas size, but than I don't like the initial layout." What it mean ? You set smaller size than required, so out of window or column will be wiped out.

Comment: Yes, but I want to know how to set the size of the container of the canvas and the buttons. If I set the canvas before the picture is set there is a big gap between Load CSV and Set Threshold buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set size of `sg.Canvas` to fit figure of `Matplotlib`, you have better specified option `figsize` and `dpi`, then you can get the size will be (figsize[0]*dpi, figsize[1]*dpi).

Method `sg.pin` is to keep the position of `sg.Canvas` when invisible. `window['-CANVAS-'].Widget.pack()` is to make it visible for no `update` method of `sg.Canvas`.

Method `contents_changed` called to update scrollbar of `sg.column`, here `window.refresh()` required to update GUI before it.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

def draw_figure(canvas, figure):
    figure_canvas_agg = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, canvas)
    figure_canvas_agg.draw()
    figure_canvas_agg.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)
    return figure_canvas_agg

column = [
    [sg.Button("Load CSVs", key="-loadcsv-")],
    [sg.pin(sg.Canvas(size=(500, 500), visible=False, key='-CANVAS2-')),
     sg.InputText(size=(10,1), key="threshold"),
     sg.Button("Set Threshold", key="-threshold-")],
    [sg.InputText(size=(50, 1), key='-MODELNAME-'),
     sg.FileBrowse("Load Model")],
]
layout = [[sg.Column(column, vertical_scroll_only=True, scrollable=True, size=(800, 400), key='-COLUMN-')]]
window = sg.Window('Demo Application - Embedding Matplotlib In PySimpleGUI', layout, finalize=True, element_justification='center', font='Helvetica 18')
fig_canvas_agg = None

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "-threshold-":
        if fig_canvas_agg is None:
            fig = matplotlib.figure.Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
            t = np.arange(0, 3, .01)
            fig.add_subplot(111).plot(t, 2 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * t))
            fig_canvas_agg = draw_figure(window['-CANVAS2-'].TKCanvas, fig)
            window['-CANVAS2-'].Widget.pack()
            window.refresh()
            window['-COLUMN-'].contents_changed()

window.close()
```

Comment: But here there would still be a gap of the 400 px between the Text and the Button. I don't want this gap before the picture is set.

Comment: You mean the white gap around the matplot figure ?

Comment: No. Before the picture is set I don't want the canvas to have allocated space

Comment: Update code as above. Your window maybe not centered after figure shown.

Comment: NO, it still gets wiped out.

Comment: It is for your code ? update code to similar as yours.

Comment: OK, it works now thanks. I didn't include the refresh and content_changed in my code, an now I did and it works.